# Multi-lines input on phantom.js console

Tags: phantomjs

Does `phantom.js` (>= 1.7.0) support multi-lines input on its console? Neither pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> nor <kbd>META</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> works below,

```
phantomjs> function foo() {
Parse error
```